# How to keep the same `ul` active after the page reload?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am working in html,css,jquery to toggle the `ul`. I want the same `ul` to be active after the page reloads.

How to do this?

My html structure is:

```
<ul id="level1" class="category">
<li class="level1 inactive">
  <a href="#">abc</a>
  <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
  <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1 inactive">
  <a href="#">xyz</a>
  <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
  <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And my jquery is :

```
       <script>  
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
      $j('li.level1').click(function() {
          $j("li.level1").addClass('inactive').removeClass("current");
          $j(this).addClass('current').removeClass('inactive');
        $j('ul#level2').hide();
       $j('ul#level2', this).show();
      });


});
</script>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use `localStorage`

Comment: can you  help me in that? am newbie to jquery.

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` is the best option for what you are looking for. You can store and get the item from `localStorage`. Consider below example.

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  var index=localStorage.getItem("liIndex"); //accessing localStorage item
  $j('li.level1').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("liIndex",$j(this).index()); //store the index of clicked element
    $j("li.level1").addClass('inactive').removeClass("current");
    $j(this).addClass('current').removeClass('inactive');
    $j('ul#level2').hide();
    $j('ul#level2', this).show();
  });
  if(index) //get the index after attaching click event
    $("li.level1").eq(index).trigger('click'); //trigger click for that element with that index
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="level1" class="category">
  <li class="level1 inactive">
    <a href="#">abc</a>
    <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1 inactive">
    <a href="#">xyz</a>
    <ul id="level2" style=" display:none;">
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="level2 inactive"><a href="#url">Level2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Since, `snippet` does not support `localStorage`, that's what it said for me at least, Here is the 

## [`JsFiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9kedou2q/1/)

 for you.

Comment: The fiddle is perfectly working. But when I click the `li` in my code, for just a second the `ul` is toggled open & it redirects to the respective `url` in the anchor tag and the full page gets reloaded.

Comment: @Ramya add `e.preventDefault()` inside `$j('li.level1').click(function() {` like `$j('li.level1').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //remaining code})` Let me know if you face issues..

Comment: I followed your guidance. Now when I click th `li` it is not getting redirected  to thr `url` and even now `ul` is getting closed when page is refreshed.
@Guruprasad Rao I want the page to get redirected to the mentioned url and also the selected li's `ul` should be still opened. Is this possible? If possible please help me.

Comment: @Ramya.. Then Sridhar's answer should definitely work.. triggering `click` is what I guess causing redirecting problem....

Comment: I tried that too but no progress. Is it possible through ajax loading? Without getting the entire page to reload.

Comment: Its possible very much, but need to understand more on what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115520/discussion-between-ramya-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Sorry @Ramya.. I had emergency.. So I had to leave.. Still facing the problem..?

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
<script>  
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
      $j('li.level1').click(function() {
            $j("li.level1").addClass('inactive').removeClass("current");
        $j(this).addClass('current').removeClass('inactive');
        $j('ul#level2').hide();
        $j('ul#level2', this).show();
              var parent = $j(this).parent().attr('id');
              localStorage.setItem('activeIndex', $j(this).index());
      });
            var currentIndex = localStorage.getItem('activeIndex');     $j('li.level1').eq(currentIndex).addClass('current').removeClass('inactive');
            $j('li.level1').eq(currentIndex).children('ul').css('display','block');
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is redirecting to the respective url but the active ul is not active after page redirect. :( am stuck.

Comment: Better to post your complete page then? Then only we will get to know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage`

To save an item

```
localStorage.setItem('last-accessed-list', 'level2');
```

To get an item

```
var lastAccessedList = localStorage.setItem('last-accessed-list');
```

For reference - [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

Please see - Only giving idea for you to explore